# ngAnimate 1.2 with ngShow/ngHide

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I am trying to add CSS3 transitions to my code, but is confused over the meaning of these classes:

```
.ng-hide-add
.ng-hide-active
```

and

```
.ng-hide-remove 
.ng-hide-remove-active
```

I was trying to add a simple ease-in & ease-out with this, but not sure which are the classes that I should add that to!

Answer (score 0):

## Coplex solution

There is complette solution with animation hide/show (complex example):
https://github.com/mirekh/Todolist_app_bootstrap

or try the example below.

## 1. HTML file

### 1.1. Put into the body of file **index.html**

> /* **File index.html (body)** */

```
<p>
    Click this: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked">
</p>
<div>
    <div class="check-element animate-show" ng-show="checked">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
        I show up when your checkbox is checked.
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="check-element animate-show" ng-hide="checked">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
        I hide when your checkbox is checked.
    </div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind 2 lines:
    + `<script src="lib/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>`
    + `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animation.css"/>`

### 1.2. Complette index.html

Complette index.html looks like this:

> /* **File index.html** */

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Todolist AngularJS App</title>
    <!-- css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animation.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <!--
    insert main code here (body from [1])
    -->

    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <!-- opional -->
    <script src="js/factories.js"></script>
    <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

## 2. CSS file

> /* **File: animations.css** */

```
.animate-show {
    -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
    transition:all linear 0.5s;
    line-height:20px;
    opacity:1;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background:white;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide-add,
.animate-show.ng-hide-remove {
    display:block!important;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide {
    line-height:0;
    opacity:0;
    padding:0 10px;
}

.check-element {
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the animate-show class on element to show/hide
add ng:show argument with corresponding expression

```
<div class="animate-show" ng:show="expression">
    My content hide and show.
</div>
```